# Fill column with max value of a sub-set in-between a specific value

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, sequence

```
lvalues = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,242,222,183,149,121,102,91,84,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,230,218,209,197,162,156,144,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
idx = range(0,len(lvalues))

dfSample = pd.DataFrame(lvalues, index=idx)
```

I have a column with several subsets in-between zeros. I would like to loop through it and use the highest value of which subset and repeat it until it reaches 0 again. For example once the loop reaches 242 repeats it until 0 starts again. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you elaborate it? make your output more clear.

Comment: @keramat I have noticed that.

I have a column with several subsets in-between zeros. I would like to loop through it and use the highest value of which subset and repeat it until it reaches 0 again. For example once the loop reaches 242 repeats it until 0 starts again.

Comment: What if the 242 was 200? Should the first group be filled with 242 or 222?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `shift` to put the the zero at line with the start of the numbers, then use `and` to condition on to combine it with the real column. Use similar procedure for specifying the end of numbers. After that you can use `cumsum` to make groups and then just `groupby` and return the first value of each `group`. Use:

```
g =(((dfSample[0].shift()==0)&(dfSample[0]!=0))|((dfSample[0].shift(-1)==0)&(dfSample[0]!=0)).shift()).astype(int).cumsum()
dfSample.groupby(g).transform(lambda x: x.iloc[0])
```

Output:

```
    0
0   0
1   0
2   0
3   0
4   0
5   0
6   0
7   0
8   242
9   242
10  242
11  242
12  242
13  242
14  242
15  242
16  0
17  0
18  0
19  0
20  0
21  0
22  0
23  0
24  0
25  230
26  230
27  230
28  230
29  230
30  230
31  230
32  0
33  0
34  0
35  0
36  0
37  0
38  0
39  0
```

Comment: it worked, do you mind to share the logic?
Thanks

Comment: This fills with the **first**, not **max** value ;)

Comment: Yes, Actually that does not matter, just it needs to be changed from first to max function in the transform. I realized that the values are sorted.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to group by consecutive 0/non-0 and get the max, use:

```
g = dfSample[0].eq(0).diff().fillna(False).cumsum()
dfSample.groupby(g).transform('max')
```

Logic: transform the series to booleans and get the diff. There will be True on each group start (except the very first item that we fill). Get the `cumsum` to form groups. Use the grouper to get the max per group.

---

If you rather want to replace by the first value of each group, a simple mask and fill should work:

```
dfSample.mask(dfSample[0].shift(fill_value=0).ne(0)).ffill(downcast='infer')
```

Logic: mask the values that are not preceded by 0, `ffill` the NaNs.

Comment: So big brain! Really impressed by this one! WOuld you mind sharing the though process?

Comment: @Zero I added a few comments, I hope it helps

Comment: @mozway This is elegant dude.